# Remove from dataframe A all not in dataframe B (huge df1, spark)

Tags: apache-spark

Let say we have 2 data-frames.

First one contains about 120 billion rows with around 25 columns, size couple terabytes. It looks like:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A1 | A1 | ... |
| A1 | A2 | A1 | ... |
| A2 | A1 | A3 | ... |
| C100 | G103 | L300 | ... |

Second contains around 300k rows with couple megabyte size
It looks like

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A1 |
| A1 | A2 |
| A2 | A1 |

I want remove all from df1 all rows not in df2.
Simple way is to do join df1.join(df2). Also I can broadcast df2 because it is very small. The question is do I have faster way to do that in spark because it takes around couple hours each run?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a faster way than

```
df1.join(broadcast(df2), Seq("ColA","ColB"),"leftsemi")
```

The "couple of hours" is probabely not spent during this join, but for other stuff you do